# Hp LaserJet CP1025nw Color Printer Isn't able to print using USB with Otg Cable Connected

Tags: java, android, printing

I have a Hp LaserJet Cp1025nw Color printer. I am able to print with wireless but with when I connected with USB cable(OTG) I am not able to print.

The Device is showing an adapter like that which are disabled **USB: HP LaserJet CP 1025nw**

I am using Samsung Galaxy A Tablet

[image]

The Spinner of Printer from the Hp printer SDK

```
 AppCompatSpinner sizeSpinner = (AppCompatSpinner) findViewById(R.id.paper_size_spinner);
    List<String> spinnerList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // add 4x5 as needed
    String text = "";
    if (PrintUtil.is4x5media) {
        text = (String) getText(R.string.preview_spinner_4x5);
        spinnerMap.put(text, PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_INDEX_4X6);
        spinnerList.add(text);
    }

    // add default media size
    for (int i = 0; i < defaultMediaSizes.length; i++) {
        text = getSpinnerText(defaultMediaSizes[i]);
        spinnerMap.put(text, defaultMediaSizes[i]);
        spinnerList.add(text);
    }

    // add media size in print items
    if(printJobData.getPrintItems() != null)
        for (PrintAttributes.MediaSize mediaSize: printJobData.getPrintItems().keySet()) {
            text = getSpinnerText(mediaSize);
            if (!spinnerList.contains(text)) {
                spinnerMap.put(text, mediaSize);
                spinnerList.add(text);
            }
        }

    // add media size from default print item if it does exist
    if (printJobData.getDefaultPrintItem() != null && printJobData.getDefaultPrintItem().getMediaSize() != null) {
        PrintAttributes.MediaSize mediaSize = printJobData.getDefaultPrintItem().getMediaSize();
        text = getSpinnerText(mediaSize);
        if (!spinnerList.contains(text)) {
            spinnerMap.put(text, mediaSize);
            spinnerList.add(text);
        }
    }

    String[] spinnerArray = spinnerList.toArray(new String[spinnerList.size()]);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sizeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(printJobData.getPrintDialogOptions() != null) {
        PrintAttributes.MediaSize mediaSize = printJobData.getPrintDialogOptions().getMediaSize();
        text = getSpinnerText(mediaSize);
        sizeSpinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(text));
    }
    setSizeSpinnerListener(sizeSpinner);
```

Has anyone faced this problem? Please Mention the solution if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disabled printers you're seeing are the Wireless ones (looks like you've printed with and hence they became favorite and would show up even if they are not in range/disoverable).
To my knowledge the HP Print Plugin does not discover printers over USB cables, but you can confirm that (or request the feature) with the app support.

Comment: yes Some Hp Printer Not Support printing over UTG Cables, My printer is in this List Thanks